# best practice to sync useRef with useState in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm often in a situation, where I like to have a reference (with `useRef`) in sync with a state (with `useState`). This is particularly useful inside stable callbacks to avoid unnecessary rerenders.

Currently I'm using this approach:

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState(...)
const valueRef = useRef(value)
valueRef.current = value
```

I've seen code where the last line is wrapped in a `useEffect` like

```js
useEffect(() => {
  valueRef.current = value
}, [value])
```

which looks more expensive as simply overwriting the previous value with the new one.

Is there a best practice for something like that?
Or is the complete concept wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

This has been called [the "latest ref pattern"](https://epicreact.dev/the-latest-ref-pattern-in-react/). I've used it to keep a ref in sync with a prop, not state, but it's the same idea.

I believe the purpose of the useLayoutEffect (or useEffect) is because assigning to `ref.current` doesn't play nicely with server-side rendering or the upcoming suspense mode. React assumes that component bodies do not have side effects, and assigning a ref's value is a side effect that React isn't guaranteed to preserve.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do by creating a custom function

```
const [ value, _setValue ] = useState(...)
const valueRef = useRef()

valueRef.current = value

const setValue = (arg) => {
   valueRef.current = arg 
   _setValue(arg)
}
```